# Why does the `const` modifier applied to a variable holding a struct value make the struct values immutable?

Tags: c++

```
struct S { string s; }

void method() 
{
    const S s = { "s" };
    s.s = "l"; // Error
}
```

I can't understand why a compile-error is being generated here. From my understanding, making a struct-referencing variable `const` should make the **variable itself** immutable (only `s = { "m" }` after `s` initialization should generate error), not the structure itself (so `s.s = "l"` should pass OK). Why const makes both the variable and the struct immutable?

Comment: Would an object really be `const` if you could change some parts of it?

Comment: No, and that's actually the question - struct's fields are not `const`, only a variable referencing a struct instance is `const`, so why the object itself becomes immutable, not only the variable?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. It's *only* through the `const` variable that you can't change the fields. You can still create another non-const variable and change the fields of that. A variable *is* an object.

Comment: @Andrey Ilyunin The qualifier const makes the object denoted by a variable immutable.

Comment: @cigien I could have `struct S { const string s; }` if I wanted the struct to be immutable. What I wanted here is a mutable struct with an immutable variable pointing to struct. But as @hobbs said there is no indirection like in Java, where you have a variable and an object inside the heap to which the variable actually points to. So if a variable is `final` in Java, and the object the variable is referencing is mutable (it's fields are not `final`, where `final` is equal to C++ `const` in many cases), then you can change the object's fields freely, but not the variable's reference value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not "a variable referencing a struct instance". There's no indirection. The value of `s` is a `struct S`, which includes all of its fields.

Comment: Ah, I see. I just come from Java background, and a syntactic analogy for this in Java is to declare a class with mutable fields, but making a variable referencing the instance of the class `final` won't make the object itself immutable. Semantics seem to be different though. Thanks!

Comment: Java isn't C++ and vice versa. You don't pay for what you don't use in C++. I recommend reading up on the distinction between the C++ concepts of **automatic storage** versus **dynamic storage**.

Comment: @bitmask I started learning C++ with Eckel's `Thinking in C++` a week ago, and if I knew this concepts before posting a question, then, actually, the question would not exist at all. So everything has it's time basically. But thanks, I'll follow the advice when it's time to learn this stuff too.

Comment: I didn't mean to fault you for not knowing this. I thought that researching storage in C++ will give you the understanding that you require to rectify the underlying misapprehensions expressed in your comment and question. To make the transition from Java to C++ I think the biggest hurdle is RAII and storage (and maybe templates).

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin C++ does have a [`mutable specifier`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) that allows a member to be modified even if the containing object is `const`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, thanks, that's useful! Basically a solution to the aforementioned "task" :)

Comment: Something to note - Thinking in C++ was written before 2011, which means that most of modern features of C++ are not mentioned there (as they just didn't exist back then). Try to use or (supplement your learning) with a more recent book.

Comment: @RazielMagius which one for instance? Nothing as nicely rated shows up among recent books, plus I'm not planning to make C++ my main language of development - it's mostly for general education and understanding what's going on under JNI layer. Won't it be more effective to understand the fundamentals and then learn new standards-specific stuff?

Comment: There is [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). If you like algorithms, Data Structures & Algorithm Analysis in C++ by Weiss covers some of the fundamental modern c++ features in first 3 chapters. Some things in old c++ is sort of obsolete  - for example move semantics which appeared in C++11 are important from the beginning - as move constructor and move assignment operator should be defined on any class that allocates resources. And there are many others...